# Magento 2.4 alter contact form post values using plugin afterExecute

Tags: magento2, plugin, after-plugin

I am trying to use a plugin to alter the contact form post data by using the afterExecute method:

```
    public function afterExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject, $result)
    {
        $comment =  $subject->getRequest()->getParam('comment', false);
        $subject->getRequest()->setParam('comment', 'testing: '.$comment); // <--- this is not working and not changing the comment post value
        return $result;
    }
```

I just want to append/prepend a string to the comment (message) that is posted.
But the above does not work and the comment post value is not changed.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use before plugin instead of after plugin.

```
public function beforeExecute(\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject)
{
    $comment =  $subject->getRequest()->getParam('comment', false);
    $subject->getRequest()->setParam('comment', 'testing: '.$comment); 
}
```

try this.

Comment: Thanks. I get this error though: Error: Cannot use object of type Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect\Interceptor as arra

Comment: Can you just debug and show here what you are getting in $result ?

Comment: i have checked actual function and it doesn't have $result return with comment, so you just have to use before plugin instead of after plugin

Comment: @sulman answer updated.

Comment: Perfect! Works well. Thank you :)

Comment: If answer works for you then you can upvote the answer so everyone can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try before plugin with below code

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Frontend\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index;

class Post
{

    public function beforeExecute(
        \Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post $subject
    ) {
        $comment =  $subject->getRequest()->getParam('comment', false);
        $subject->getRequest()->setParam('comment', 'testing: '.$comment);
        return;
    }
}
```